# How do I disable IntelliJ automatic formatting for static arrays?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In some TestNG data providers, I have static array initializations that look like this:

```
return new Object[][] {
    {"Foo", "Bar"},
    {"Baz", "Quux"}
};
```

Since these are short lines, IntelliJ keeps wanting to reformat this onto a single line, but I want to keep it as-is for readability and future diffs. What option under `Editor > Code Style > Java` will preserve this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your requirement the best setting for you should be

***Wrapping and Braces*** -> ***Array Initializer***

- Put ***Wrap always***.
- Check(tick) all the options ***Align when multiline*** | ***New line after '{'*** | ***Place '}' on new line***.

[image]

Comment: Aha! I had these all checked but the wrapping was set to "wrap with long". This gives me the most consistent behavior. It's a little more verbose than I need for short lines but at least now it doesn't try to join them together.